# Unable to click on Crop button on Edit Image pop-up

Tags: ajax, selenium-webdriver, jcrop

i need to automate following functional flow using selenium webdriver

1. click on Upload button
2. select an image from local directory
3. an Edit image pop-up will appear with crop overlay and crop image button
4. click on Crop Image button to crop and submit the button

I could select an image using robot however I could not click on an Crop Image button which appears on Edit Image pop-up. please find HTML snippets of Edit Image pop as below

```
    <div id="edt-img-popup" style="left: 193px; position: absolute; top: 1045px; z-index: 902; opacity: 1; display: block;">
<span class="button bClose"><span>X</span></span>
<div id="edited-img"><img style="display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 980px; height: 710px;" src="http://locallocation?img=mQzJ0jI8si.jpg" id="artistImgCrop" height="710.673224715647" width="980"><div class="jcrop-holder" style="width: 980px; height: 710px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 600; width: 980px; height: 653px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 310; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"><img style="border: medium none; visibility: visible; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 980px; height: 710px;" src="locallocation?img=mQzJ0jI8si.jpg"><div class="jcrop-hline" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.4;"></div><div class="jcrop-hline bottom" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.4;"></div><div class="jcrop-vline right" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.4;"></div><div class="jcrop-vline" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.4;"></div><div style="cursor: move; position: absolute; z-index: 360;" class="jcrop-tracker"></div></div><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 320; display: block;"><div class="ord-n jcrop-dragbar" style="cursor: n-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 370;"></div><div class="ord-s jcrop-dragbar" style="cursor: s-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 371;"></div><div class="ord-e jcrop-dragbar" style="cursor: e-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 372;"></div><div class="ord-w jcrop-dragbar" style="cursor: w-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 373;"></div><div class="ord-n jcrop-handle" style="cursor: n-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 374; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-s jcrop-handle" style="cursor: s-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 375; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-e jcrop-handle" style="cursor: e-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 376; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-w jcrop-handle" style="cursor: w-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 377; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-nw jcrop-handle" style="cursor: nw-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 378; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-ne jcrop-handle" style="cursor: ne-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 379; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-se jcrop-handle" style="cursor: se-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 380; opacity: 0.5;"></div><div class="ord-sw jcrop-handle" style="cursor: sw-resize; position: absolute; z-index: 381; opacity: 0.5;"></div></div></div><div style="width: 984px; height: 714px; position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px; z-index: 290; cursor: crosshair;" class="jcrop-tracker"></div><input class="jcrop-keymgr" style="position: fixed; left: -120px; width: 12px;" type="radio"><img style="display: block; visibility: visible; width: 980px; height: 710px; border: medium none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.6;" src="http://locallocation?img=mQzJ0jI8si.jpg" height="710.673224715647" width="980"></div></div>
<!-- This is the form that our event handler fills -->
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" id="img_crp_form">
    <input value="0" id="x" name="image[x]" type="hidden">
    <input value="0" id="y" name="image[y]" type="hidden">
    <input value="980" id="w" name="image[w]" type="hidden">
    <input value="653.3333333333334" id="h" name="image[h]" type="hidden">
    <input value="980" id="maxW" name="image[maxW]" type="hidden">
    <input value="710.673224715647" id="maxH" name="image[maxH]" type="hidden">
    <input value="http://locallocation?img=mQzJ0jI8si.jpg" id="slctdImgUrl" name="image[url]" type="hidden">
    <input id="cropImage" value="Crop Image" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" type="submit">
</form>
```

I've tried following approaches but it did not work
1. switchTo frame
2. window handles
3. wait - implicit, explicit, ajax

any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your implementation and also share the site URL if its publicly available ?

Comment: sorry, could not share the site. this is what i've tried

          driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("edt-img-popup")));
     driver.findElement(By.id("cropImage")).click();
     waitForAjax();
     driver.switchTo().defaultContent();


even this one

              WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
    {public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) 
        {return isElementPresent(By.id(".//*[@id='cropImage']"),20);}
    });
     driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='cropImage']")).click();

Comment: and this as well


and this as well

    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("cropImage"));
     Actions crop = new Actions(driver);
     crop.moveToElement(image);
     crop.build();
     crop.perform();}